# Wide dataframe and longer dataframe transfer

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas, how can I transfer a wide dataframe to a longer dataframe? (`ori_df` to `new_df` as in the image.)

On the contrast, how can I transfer `new_df` to  `ori_df`?

```
import pandas as pd
ori_df=pd.DataFrame()
ori_df=pd.DataFrame([['a','1'],['w:','z'],['t','6'],['f:','z'],['a','2']],
                    columns=['type','value'])
```

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73268851/edit) (it covers program input as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
pd.melt(ori_df,id_vars='type',var_name='item',value_name='amount')
```

or

```
(ori_df.set_index('type')
.stack()
.sort_index(level=-1,ascending=False)
.rename_axis(['type','item'])
.reset_index(name = 'amount'))
```